# Injecting routerProvider for AngularJS test using Jasmine

Tags: angularjs, testing, jasmine, provider, inject

I'm using Jasmine for testing AngularJS controller and I'm struggling to find a way of injecting $routeProvider into the module.

Here's my controller:

```
var app = angular.module('testApp', []);

app.config(['$routeProvider',
  function ($routeProvider) {
      $routeProvider.
          when('/smth', {
              templateUrl: 'smth.html',
              controller: 'testController'
          });
  }]);

app.controller('testController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.data = 'GG';
}]);
```

Here's my test:

```
describe('Test Suite', function () {
    var myScope, ctrl;

    beforeEach(module('testApp'));

    beforeEach(inject(function ($controller, $rootScope) {
        myScope = $rootScope.$new();
        ctrl = $controller('testController', {
            $scope: myScope
        });
    }));

    it('data is GG', function () {
        expect(myScope.data).toEqual('GG');
    });
});
```

When I try to run it, I receive a following error:

```
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module testApp due to:
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $routeProvider
```

But if I try to run again - I get this:

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'myScope.data')
```

Errors keep alternating if tests are run again. I'm using Visual Studio 2013 and Resharper 8 to run the Jasmine tests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the angular-route bower component to your project and then inject the ngRoute into your module like this

```
var app = angular.module('testApp', ['ngRoute']);
app.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.
      when('/smth', {
          templateUrl: 'smth.html',
          controller: 'testController'
      });
}]);

app.controller('testController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.data = 'GG';
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

First make sure you have included **angular-route.min.js**. 
This module has been separated from angularJs library, so you have will have to include it separately

then make sure you have added dependency for your module to ngRoute
e.g. **angular.module('testApp', ['ngRoute']);**

then in the test make sure you inject **$route** so its available in your tests as well